# What happens on a CLR GC cycle?

Tags: c#

Are all threads suspended?

... and how long does a full collection take?

Comment: The GC allows your threads to get to a safe place (outside any memory barriers, for example) before it hijacks your threads to allow garbage collection.  This is not the same as Suspending the thread using a Windows API call, since the CLR is managing the execution.  When it's done, the actual pointer references underlying your managed references may actually be pointing to different places on the heap than before, which keeps unmanaged/managed interop interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. all managed threads are suspended except for the thread that triggered the garbage collection

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx

Comment: By default, .NET uses concurrent garbage collection on workstations (documented later in that article).